# operator overloading for pointer to struct

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to compare values of two pointers to structure "Node" in a class. Although I overloaded the < operator, I'm not sure whether it's the right way to do that because when I run the code I get right answer sometimes and sometimes it compares them wrong. Is that possible to compare the value properties this way? (I have to use pointers to Node, I can't do it other way). Why results are different each time I run the program?
Thanks for helping!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "compare.h"

struct Node {
    int value;
    bool operator >(const Node &n) { return value > n.value ; };
    bool operator <(const Node &n) { return value < n.value; };

};

int main()
{
    Node *a;
    a = new Node;
    a->value = 1;
    test<Node *> t;
    t.compare(a);
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compare.h file:

```
template<class TYPE>
class test {
public:
    void compare(const TYPE n);
    test();
    ~test();
private:
    TYPE n;
};

template<class TYPE>
inline void test<TYPE>::compare(const TYPE a)
{
        if (n > a)
            std::cout << "n > a";
        else if (a>n)
            std::cout << "n < a";

}

template<class TYPE>
inline test<TYPE>::test()
{
    n = new Node;
    n->value = 2;
}

template<class TYPE>
inline test<TYPE>::~test()
{
    delete n;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Your operator takes `const Node&` and you're passing `const TYPE&`, but `TYPE = Node*` and not `Node`. Use `TYPE = Node` and take `TYPE*` as your arguments in `test`. Then ask yourself, how any other `TYPE` would work, when you assign `n = new Node`.

Comment: You're comparing `Node*` (ie: a pointer to a node); so the comparison check you're doing is checking whether the memory address is higher or lower than another. You'll want to either use `test<Node>` so that you're comparing `Node` **values**, or you'll want to *dereference* the `Node*` in `compare` (eg: `if (*n > *a)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you're instantiating `test` with template parameter `Node*`

```
test<Node *> t;
```

In your `test::compare` function, you're comparing against the template parameter

```
template<class TYPE>
inline void test<TYPE>::compare(const TYPE a)
{
        if (n > a)
            std::cout << "n > a";
        else if (a>n)
            std::cout << "n < a";
}
```

If you substitute `TYPE` for the parameter you used, `Node*`, you'll get the following:

```
inline void test::compare(const Node* a)
{
        if (n > a)
            std::cout << "n > a";
        else if (a>n)
            std::cout << "n < a";
}
```

So you can see that you're comparing `Node*` values. That means you're comparing the **memory address** of `n` vs `a`.

You can fix this by *dereferencing* the pointer first

```
template<class TYPE>
inline void test<TYPE>::compare(const TYPE a)
{
        if (*n > *a)
            std::cout << "n > a";
        else if (*a > *n)
            std::cout << "n < a";
}
```

Comment: Well said. I just want to add that OP needs to be wary now because they'll get a compiler error if they try to call `compare` for non-dereference-able types. Perhaps two functions should be written to handle both scenarios.

Comment: Thanks so much for your elegant  explanation.

Comment: @gru97 it is my pleasure!